# Remove Numerical Values If Less Than N%

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, grep

I need to delete any numerical values less than `30%` in some text files. Below is the text file contents and the current code I'm using to achieve this.

I'm looking for a better, more efficient way to do this.

**file1.csv**

```
25%
80%
22%
67%
45%
30%
15%
5%
13%
```

**file2.csv**

```
25% 80% 22% 67% 45% 30% 15% 5% 13%
```

**Code:**

```
sed -i 's/30%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/29%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/28%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/27%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/26%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/25%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/24%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/23%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/22%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/21%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/20%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/19%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/18%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/17%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/16%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/15%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/14%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/13%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/12%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/11%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/10%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/9%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/8%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/7%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/6%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/5%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/4%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/3%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/2%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/1%//g' file.csv
sed -i 's/0%//g' file.csv
```

Comment: `s/0%//g` will change `10%` to `1`.

Comment: Is `100%` existing in the files? Or `123%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do not mind using **Perl**

for your both multi-lines or single line you can:

```
perl -pe 's/[0-2][0-9]%|^[0-9]%| +[0-9]%//g' file
```

and if you do not want the empty line then try:

```
perl -pe 's/[0-2][0-9]%|^[0-9]%| +[0-9]%//g && s/\r?\n//g' file
```

## or

```
perl -lne 'print $& while /[3-9][0-9]%/g' file
```

## or

`grep` with `-P`

```
grep -Po '[3-9][0-9]%' file
```

Comment: The second answer here worked best for me! Thanks @k-five

Answer (score 1):

try with simple awk.

```
awk '$0+0>=30'  Input_file
```

Comparing digit value of each line with 30, so if they are equal or greater than 30 then print them.(Basically awk works on method of condition then action, so here I am not mentioning any action so whenever condition is TRUE it will do default action which is printing the current line.)

In case you need to save new output into same Input_file then run following.

```
awk '$0+0>=30' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

**EDIT:** As OP added one more type of file to be processed so adding this solution too now.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i+0>=30){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":" ")}};print ""}'  file2.csv
```

Comment: Please see edit. This code doesn't seem to work with one line (file2.csv) of percentages?

Comment: @arnpry: kindly see my edit now and let me know if you have any queries on same.

Answer (score 1):

Simply with ***sed***:

```
sed -Ei '/^([0-9]|[12][0-9])%/d' file.csv
```

- `d` - subcommand, deletes lines matched the pattern

The output:

```
80%
67%
45%
30%
```

---

Note, to detele also `30%` your condition should be set as **less than or equal** `30%`

**----------**

To filter out values from single line file use the following:

```
sed -Ei 's/[[:space:]]*\<([0-9]|[12][0-9])%//g' file2.csv
```

The output:

```
 80% 67% 45% 30%
```

Comment: Please see edit. This code doesn't seem to work with one line (file2.csv) of percentages?

Comment: @arnpry, that's because you did not mention about one-line file at start

Comment: Sorry about that! I realized I needed that option as well and edited the original post.